# Rule updation fails in Drools

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I am drools version 5.6.0.Final and facing below issue.
I am using declarative model for creating dynamic pojos.

--> All new pojos goes in decare.drl file
--> All rules using the above pojos(declared in declare.drl) goes in rules.drl file

When first time knowledge base is created, compilation goes well and all rules will be triggred correcly as expected. But when I update a rule in rules.dl file, knowledge agent fails in compiling this rules.drl file as it is has pojos declared in another file i.e. declare.drl

So agent gets only rules.drl file for compilation due to this is the only file updated and he does not get declare.drl. So incremental build fails.

## Getting the below error: Server is a pojo declared in declare.drl file

## Error Unable to resolve ObjectType 'Server'

Please let me know how to make it work and agent should be able to compile it properly.

Thank you in advance,
Hariprasad Taduru

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you're referencing POJOs in DRL files without bothering to import them in the headers of those DRL files? This behaviour is not inconsistent with what would be expected if a Java class fails to import the classes it references.

Comment: importing is taken care already.
Anyway I fixed it by making all the declared pojos and rule files under the same package.
Thank you